# JQGrid form edit: Modify elmprefix of column dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I added some code for the initial condition,  in case anyone is interested;  I placed this code in the Country datainit:

```
    setTimeout(function ()
                            {
                                var required = $(elem).val() === 'US';
                                grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'PostalCode', { editrules: { required: required} });
                                $('#PostalCode').siblings('.mystar').html(required ? '*' : '&nbsp;');
                            }, 100);
```

(I understand that the new release of JQGrid does away with the need for the setTimeout, but I am having issues with the upgrade.)

---

I need to dynamically set the elmprefix of a formedit column.  The idea is, for the US, a postal code is required.  The required element is functioning, but the elmprefix does not show.

```
dataEvents: [
    {
        type: "change",
        fn: function (e) {
            changeStateSelect($(e.target).val(), e.target);
            var isUS = $(e.target).val() == 'US';
            grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'PostalCode', { editrules: { required: isUS },
                formoptions: { elmprefix: (isUS ? "<font color='red'>*</font>" : " ")}
            });
        } 
    },
    {
        type: "keyup",
        fn: function (e) { $(e.target).trigger('change'); }
    }
]
```

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `formoptions.elmprefix` and other properties of `formoptions` will be used *before* the edit form will be created. You can use callback `beforeInitData` or event `jqGridAddEditBeforeInitData` to modify the data before the form will be created.

If you really need to show/hide the asterisk dynamically you can just hide the corresponding element manually. For example you can define `elmprefix` as

```
elmprefix: "<span class='mystar' style='color:red'>*</span>"
```

to be able easy find and modify it. Then you can use

```
$("#PostalCode").siblings(".mystar").html($(e.target).val() === 'US' ? "*" : "&nbsp;");
```

inside of `change` handler instead of `grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'PostalCode', ...);`